# How to make the keyboard ready in a EditText(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have in my layout a `EditText` and I don't want the user to click on it of the keyboard to appear but to be ready, I think this is something you put in the layout file but I really don't what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the basise `<requestFocus />` on your layout (as describe [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#requestfocus-element)) or use the function `requestFocus()` of the EditText on the `onCreate` method of the Activity/Fragment (as describe [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()))

Answer (score 0):

the property you are looking for is called **`focusable...`** and you need to set it **true**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/PhoneNumberInput"
    android:hint="Numero telefonico"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" 
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hide the Keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(serverURL.getWindowToken(), 0);

//Show the Keyboard
imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(serverURL.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

but under post runnable over the view.